# Image of imageview not remove?

Tags: android

I have an ImageView after getting id from xml.as
 on ImageView we set clicklistener which open gallery and camera opetion you can set    image from camera as well gallery 
ain #2

```
   profileimage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.profileimage);
    profileimage.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.no_img);

  protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
        Intent intent) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
    if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
        // TODO
        return;
    }
    Log.e("request code", "1:" + requestCode);
    switch (requestCode) {
    case CAMERA_SELECT:
        Log.e("in camera select", "1");
        // Get the camera data
        cameracalling(intent);

        break;
    case Gallery_Select:
        ongallerycalling(intent,resultCode);

    }
}

private void cameracalling(Intent intent){

     Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) intent.getExtras().get("data"); 
     profileimage.setImageBitmap(photo);
 }


profileimage.buildDrawingCache();

Bitmap bmap = profileimage.getDrawingCache();

ByteArrayOutputStream bao = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

bmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, bao);

byte [] ba = bao.toByteArray();

bitmapString=Base64.encodeBytes(ba);


Drawable draw = LoadImageFromWebOperations("" + objUserInformationSitesList.getProfileImage());

profileimage.setBackgroundDrawable(draw);
```

We are sending bitmap string to server image upload on server properly but when we open next time this screen that webservice call on which we upload image which will give all data (actually this user profile screen) .when we set  server image then default image also set on background

`objUserInformationSitesList` this object which contains all information after parsing   the web service. behind profile image ,default image also looking which set by me on number #1

if I unable to explain properly then please tell me.

Answer (score 1):

use in onclicklistener
profileimage.setBackgroundResource(0);

Answer (score 1):

You should replace below line:

```
profileimage.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.no_img);
```

with this line:

```
profileimage.setImageResource(R.drawable.no_img);
```

You set the image as the background of drawable and later you set bitmap as image source. So imageview background doesn't change. You should set image as image resource.